# Getting $X$ value between two numbers

Tags: expected-value

Let's assume a variable $X$:

- When we have a value of $100$ -> $X$ will be $50$.
- When we have a value of $200$ -> $X$ will be $25$.

That means $X$ decreased with a steady value a total of $25$ from $100$ to $200$.

The question is if the value is $150$ (or in my case any value from $100$ to $200$), what is the value of $X$ based on these $2$ conditions.

Comment: Do you want $X=75-\frac Y4$ or $X=\frac{5000}{Y}$ or something else?

Comment: I want the value of $X$ in a certain range (100 - 200), knowing the two conditions I mentioned above.

Comment: It would help if you gave more information about how the value $X$ is calculated. The two examples in Henry's comment above both seem to work just fine. However, there are many others that will also work.

Comment: The $X$ always has a static value, in this case its 50 when the value is 100 & 25 when the value is 200.

Comment: Right, but there are lots of ways $X$ could change as your variable $V$ does.  It could follow a straight line, or could decay exponentially, or could move up and down like a piston over time.  Knowing more about the system will let you decide what kind of interpolation to do to get the best approximation.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but the problem assumes $X$ decline or incline as a constant increase/decrease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general problem is called [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). Assuming linear interpolation, you have $(V_1, X_1) = (100, 50)$ and $(V_2, X_2) = (200, 25)$.  The equation $X = \frac{-25}{100} V + 75$ is the line through those two points, and predicts $X = 37.5$ for $V=150$.